# How do I convert this JSON to a object (model)?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization

My JSON looks something like this...

```
[
    {"success":{"id1":200}},
    {"failed":{"id6":true}},
    {"success":{"id8":"test"}}
]
```

Now I need to figure out how to get this into a model.

I presume my model should look something like this:

```
Public Class ResultModel

    Public Enum ResultStatus
        success
        failed
    End Enum


    Public Class IdResult
        Public Property ID As String
        Public Property Data As Object
    End Class


    Public Property Status As ResultStatus
    Public Property IDs As List(Of IdResult)
End Class
```

But I can't figure out how to get the JSON into a list of the ResultModel?

I know I have to do something like this...

```
Dim l As List(Of ResultModel) = DirectCast(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ResultModel))(myJSONString), List(Of ResultModel))
```

But I simply can't figure this one out.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: With the JSON on the clipboard **Edit Menu** -> **Paste Special** -> **Paste JSON as Classes**  VS will create the classes for you

Comment: Well the Paste JSON as Classes "hardcoded" id1, id6, id8 from my sample above ... I might get something like id2, id5, id12, id20 etc. So it must not be "hardcoded".

Comment: What is your expected output here?  In your JSON, each item in the array has exactly one "id object", but in your code you have the `ResultModel` containing a *list* of `IdResult`s.  Are you trying to combine all the successes together and all the failures together such that you end up with a list of exactly two `ResultModel`s, each with multiple `IdResult`s?  Or are you trying to have your models match the JSON such that you will end up with the same number of `ResultModels` as there are items in the original array and each `ResultModel` will contain a list of exactly one `IdResult`?